# Unable to login Ubunutu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, chromebook

I am new to Ubuntu. I did not do any updates or anything recently but for some reason I can only login to the guest account. It does not take me through a login loop, the screen flashes and just stays stuck on the blank background, and then I have to restart the computer. I am using an Acer C720 if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: You could enter a TTY session and reinstall `unity` and `ubuntu-desktop` from there possibly. I think it's `ctrl`+`alt`+`F1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you need to add a new user account.

First, restart. As soon as the BIOS screen disappears, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>. When you see what is called a "GRUB" screen, you need to select the Advanced options for Ubuntu and then chose "Recovery Mode".

When you see a screen with about 8 options, you need to use the arrow keys to select "Drop to Root Terminal".

Then when that opens, run the following commands:

```
adduser username
```

then you will see this (in this example, I replaced `username` with `twimmy`:

```
Adding user `twimmy' ...
Adding new group `twimmy' (1001) ...
Adding new user `twimmy' (1001) with group `twimmy' ...
Creating home directory `/home/twimmy' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
```

Then it asks for the username twice:

```
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
```

If it's successful, it asks for this:

```
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for twimmy
```

It asks the following info, make sure to enter a name (as it's used at the login screen).

```
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: Tim Hitchins
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
```

Now we need to give the user `sudo` privileges with this command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo username
```

and then restart and boot as normal. You should be able to login with the user you just created!

Comment: This worked for me I have logged in. For some reason it won't allow me to access all of the files in my other account(the one that stopped working). I want to be able to access all of them, then delete the account altogether. Also, is this just something that I will have to do over again if it happens again or do you know of any fixes? Thanks again!!